# How to get value from array and store in variable? Coldfusion

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a one dimensional array that has 3 values in it.  I need to access the value at index 2 and store it in a variable.`<cfoutput><cfset myvar= #myarray[2]#></cfoutput>`
When I try this I get the following error "Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values."  Any help would be appreciated.

Adding in extra code

```
                <cfset myarray=ArrayNew(1)>
                <cfset counter = 1>
                <cfloop list="#url.TableName#" index="y">

                <cfquery name="findgreatest" dbtype ="query">
                SELECT max(arn) as recno from qSort
                WHERE tbl = '#y#'
                </cfquery>


                <cfset nextTBRC[counter] = ["#findgreatest.recno#"]>



                <cfset counter = counter + 1>


                </cfloop>
                <cfoutput>
                <cfset myvar = "#nextTBRC[2]#">     
                <div>#myvar#</div>
                </cfoutput>
```

Comment: What does `myArray` look like?

Comment: It has 3 values in it that are simple numbers 1, 3, 7.

Comment: As with most questions, the most complete code is usually helpful.  I've attached some code that works.  Does yours look similar: `<cfset myArray[1] = 1>
<cfset myArray[2] = 2>
<cfset myArray[3] = 3>
<cfdump var="#myArray#">
<cfoutput><cfset myvar= #myarray[2]#></cfoutput>
<cfdump var="#myVar#">`

Comment: I've added more code so that you can see how it's constructed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are assigning an array:

```
<cfset nextTBRC[counter] = ["#findgreatest.recno#"]>
```

Should be:

```
<cfset nextTBRC[counter] = findgreatest.recno>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I'm still fairly new to all this.  I'm getting to the point where I'm starting to feel more comfortable, but little stuff like this really brings me down.  Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. ColdFusion supports object literal notation; one can create arrays with [] and structures with {}. You don't normally need ## in variable assignments, except for separating a CF statement from a string, e.g. <cfset s = "string #a_string_vairable#">, which could also be achieved by concatenation, i.e. <cfset s = "string " & a_string_vairable>. (For some reason, you'd also need the pounds in <cfdump var="#a_variable#"> and <cfparam name="whatever_name" default="#StructNew()#">, if the latter is to be populated with a complex data type, with or without quotes employed.)